What do the dashed lines between the contacts mean? What does ON & OFF mean here?
Here I've shown 2 selector switch symbols almost having same symbol (but different purpose, I know that.)  I have 2 questions.

What do ON (dashed lines)and OFF (solid lines) indicate?
Why there are dashed lines between all the contacts of 43-S03 but only between 23-24 & 33-34 of 43-S11?

When the contacts are closed, then the concerned circuit is isolated. Contacts 13-14 for both switches are used for feedback and the other two contacts are actually used in isolating the circuit.



GoodEngineer - Hi, Where did the images come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online, public & legal, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book / private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY (More rules in [tour] & [help].)


What does the dashed lines between the contacts mean?

The dashed line means that the contacts are mechanically linked.

what does ON & OFF mean here?

When the button is pushed the contacts close and this is the "ON" position of the switch.

Why there is dashed lines between all the contacts of 43-S03 but only between 23-24 & 33-34 of 43-S11?

I expect it's a slight oversight in the diagram. They should all be mechanically linked.

When the contacts are closed, then the concerned circuit is isolated.

When contacts close they become connected and thus, the circuit is not isolated.

In the diagrams of the isolating switches you've provided, there are a couple of key details to focus on regarding the contact representations and the indicated switch positions:
ON (dashed lines) & OFF (solid lines) indication:

The dashed lines typically represent the contacts in the closed position, meaning that the electrical circuit is complete, and current can flow through these contacts. This is indicated by the position marked "ON".
The solid lines generally represent the contacts in the open position, meaning that the circuit is broken, and no current flows through these contacts. This is indicated by the position marked "OFF".
Differences in contact lines between 43-S03 and 43-S11:
The complete dashed lines between all contacts of 43-S03 suggest that when this switch is in the "ON" position, all contacts (23-24, 33-34, and 13-14) are closed, ensuring that the entire circuit connected via these contacts is operational.
For the 43-S11 switch, the dashed lines only between contacts 23-24 and 33-34 in the "ON" position indicate that these contacts are closed, while contact 13-14 might have a different control or operational behavior (like feedback signaling) as per the design requirement of the switch in its specific application.
The configuration where dashed lines are not present between some contacts, such as between 13 and 14 in the 43-S11 when compared to 43-S03, can be due to different functions assigned to these contacts.
Contacts 13-14 in both switches are mentioned as being used for feedback, which might not require closure in the same conditions as the other contacts, depending on the switch's specific role and the electrical system's design.

